# axios-mock-adapter: MockAdapter constructor returns promise in test file

Tags: javascript, typescript, axios, jestjs, axios-mock-adapter

I'm trying to use "axios-mock-adapter" lib to mock my API requests.

Following the documentation, I need to create an instance of MockAdapter and use it in test cases. But actually, it returns a Promise and follows the next error "mock.onGet is not a function".

Code:

```
import MockAdapter from "axios-mock-adapter";
import axios from "axios";

const mock = new MockAdapter(axios.create());

it("should mock", () => {
  mock.onGet("/test", { data: "test" });

  expect(true).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Error:

```
mock.onGet is not a function
TypeError: mock.onGet is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/api/__tests__/api.test.ts:7:8)
    at Promise.then.completed (/Users/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/jest-circus/build/utils.js:391:28)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
```

I tried to resolve a promise that MockAdapter returns, but it throws a new error.

axios: ^1.3.3
axios-mock-adapter: ^1.21.2

Answer (score 0):

After many attempts, I accidentally solved it by adding "transformIgnorePatterns" to the jest config.

```
"transformIgnorePatterns": [
  "/node_modules/(?!axios)"
]
```

Comment: I'm facing the same issue but sadly, this fix doesn't work for me. I still see a promise being returned.